# Display 3d image in python

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, 3d, autoencoder

I want to convert a 2d image into 3d voxels using deep learning. So I wrote an Autoencoder and the output image is of the shape `(107, 64, 12, 3)`.

However, when I try to display the image, I am not able to. I have tried various libraries like `plotly`, `matplotlib`, `open3d` but none of them work. I tried `open3d.geometry.VoxelGrid(res, x_y_z = [64, 107, 12])` but I get the following error:

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 1 # plt.imshow(res)
> 2 # plt.show()
> ----> 3 voxel_grid = open3d.geometry.VoxelGrid(res, x_y_z = [107, 64, 12])
>
> TypeError: **init**(): incompatible constructor arguments. The
> following argument types are supported:
> 1. open3d.open3d_pybind.geometry.VoxelGrid()
> 2. open3d.open3d_pybind.geometry.VoxelGrid(arg0: open3d.open3d_pybind.geometry.VoxelGrid)
>
> Invoked with: array([[[[0.00000000e+00, 9.38580371e-03,
> 9.13413940e-04],
> [5.13529638e-03, 5.23466291e-03, 1.24680880e-03],

I can't figure out which `plotly` function to use.

What should I do?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by `output image is of the shape (107, 64, 12, 3)`

Comment: So I am new to 3D image processing. So I followed this:
https://www.kaggle.com/shivamb/3d-convolutions-understanding-use-case

as a reference and I thought that maybe I need to get the image of shape (X,Y,Z,RGB value). So that's why I made the output of the neural network of that shape.